# How to take user input in playground in Swift?

Tags: swift, input, command, command-line-interface, swift-playground

I want to take user input from command line. I'm using `readLine()` but I'm unable give any input.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36937436/exc-i386-gpflt-in-swift-code-using-xcode-playground. There's no way to use command line user input in a Playground. It only works in a real command line application.

Answer (score 2):

Create a playground with a Single View and add a UITextView and an enter button.

Answer (score 1):

In playground it is not possible to take an input from user.
Playground is just a launcher of your swift code.

sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Declare it in following way
Var a = readLine()

Comment: This has no effect in Swift Playgrounds code.